# How to loadData from string in WebView

Tags: android

How to load data from string value on webview? I've try this:

```
web.loadData(getResource().getString(R.string.webdata), "text/html","UTF-8");
```

But it get error. Please, help me.

Comment: Please explain, **in detail**, what "it get error" means. Also, please provide the string resource file where you have defined `webdata`.

Comment: I say get error because it force close, and the webdata contain html code. like<pre><code><html><body></body></html></code></pre>

Comment: "I say get error because it force close" -- then use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this. Also, please note that your HTML is invalid.

Comment: I use AIDE, and my code is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
WebView webview = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("", data, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```